# how to get content in same div without getting in many boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have following code

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                 <div id="statbox">
                       {% for obj in product_type %}
                       {% for obj1 in vastu %}
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var product  = "{{ obj.type_product }}";
                            var product1 = "{{ name }}";
                            var vastu    = "{{ obj1.vastu_key.id }}";
                            var type_id  = "{{ obj.id }}";

                            if (vastu == type_id)
                            {
                            var title = "{{ obj1.title }}";
                            var brand = "{{ obj1.brand }}";
                            var img   = "{{ obj1.image }}";
                            var price = "{{ obj1.price }}";

                            $("#statbox").prepend("<div id='box2'>"
                                                + title
                                                + brand
                                                + price
                                                +"</div>");
                            }
                        </script>
                            {% endfor %}
                         {% endfor %}
                 </div>
```

I am using two for loops here and the box2 which is styled in css, by running this code i got box2 multiple times as content contains in child for loop and that title,brand,img,price is displyed in each new box2.
But i want new box2 should be generate only according to content contains in parent for loop not according to content contains in child for loop
and the all contents i.e. title,brand,img,price which are associated with each content of parent for loop should disply in same box2. 
Multiple box2 only create according to parent for loop and contents of child for loop in the same box2 created by parent for loop.
Thank you....

Comment: Create a JS object and loop that instead of this horrific mess. Also change the ID to class

Comment: multpile box2 ids... noooooooooooo!  Also, by the looks of things, you don't even output anything from `product_type` so what is the need for the outer loop?

Comment: @Pete No i need that parent for loop coz i want child loop contents under product_type...

Comment: @mplungjan Can you give example on my problem?

Comment: @saket_tarwade ah I didn't see the `vastu == type_id`

Comment: @saket_tarwade - Have a look at my answer. I do not do Django, but I am pretty sure it is close to what you want

Comment: If you need javascript to do something with data passed from django, it's much more maintainable and clean to pass that data from your django backend as a json data structure. You can use python's `json` module in your view function and render the json in your template, or use something like _Django Rest Framework_ and get the data into your javascript with an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JS object and loop that . Also change the ID to class

Something like this:

```js
var boxes = [
  {% for obj in product_type %}
    {
    {% for obj1 in vastu %}
     "product":"{{ obj.type_product }}",
     "product1":"{{ name }}",
     "vastu": "{{ obj1.vastu_key.id }}",
     "type_id":"{{ obj.id }}"
     {% if obj1.vastu_key.id == obj.id %}
     ,
     "title":"{{ obj1.title }}",
     "brand":"{{ obj1.brand }}",
     "img":"{{ obj1.image }}",
     "price":"{{ obj1.price }}"
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   }
   {% endfor %}
];                         
$.each(boxes,function(obj) {
  $("#statbox").prepend("<div class='box2'>"
   + obj.title || ""
   + obj.brand || ""
   + obj.price || """
   +"</div>");
});
```